# how to create nodejs and mongo creat

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to print the data collection using nodejs and mongo, but it gives an error, what is the solution to the problem?

Example Schema;

```
const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

const BookCollection = mongoose.model("Book", BookSchema)

module.exports = { BookCollection, bookSchema }
```

nodejs code;

```
route.get("/books", (req, res, next) => {

    BookCollection.create({
      name: 'Ayn Rand'
    })
```

Error :

```
(node:5657) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5657) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Lisa, Your code seems incomplete can you post whole file?

Comment: I can not send the whole file, but you can understand it through the codes I send

Comment: By your route, I can see you are trying to fetch the data, is that correct?

Comment: Yes true, I can not understand why I can not create

Answer (score 0):

Then can be many reasons why you can't create, can you try like the log said to add try catch ?

It will perhaps give you more information

example :

```
route.get("/books", async (req, res, next) => {

        try {
          await BookCollection.create({
            name: 'Ayn Rand'
          });
        }catch(err){
          console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
});
```

Comment: I get this error
{"errors":{"owner":{"message":"Path `owner` is required.","name":"ValidatorError","properties":{"type":"required","message":"Path `{PATH}` is required.","path":"owner"},"kind":"required","path":"owner","$isValidatorError":true}},"_message":"Book validation failed","message":"Book validation failed: owner: Path `owner` is required.","name":"ValidationError"}

Comment: Strange, you don't specify something like "owner" , how to you import the BookCollection  that you use in the middleware ?

Comment: const BookCollection = mongoose.model("Book", BookSchema)   here you give "BookSchema" not the previously created "bookSchema"

Comment: The problem is still going on, I can not create

Comment: Yes the same mistake, I do not know how to reach the solution

Comment: Do you have another "model" named Book ? What this property "owner" come from ?

Comment: There is no other model

Comment: We can't really help you without more detail,  the error is clear it expect to have a property "owner" that you don't provided.

btw it has nothing to do with your bug but it's a strange behaviour to create an object in database on a "get" query,  it should be "post"